# Error detected when opening a Mathematica file

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In the last time when I wanted to save my Mathematica file, something was strange. Now when I want to open my file, it take too long and at the end just I see a few data and also I can not use that.

I have uploaded my file here:

http://www.mediafire.com/?4etrrd3rauq0j59

Could you please open that file and explain to me how did you do that and send to me again?

This message appears in Mathematica after long time:

> There appears to be an error in the file named below. You should close it without saving, then check the "Parse and load entire notebook into memory upon opening" checkbox in the Notebook Options dialog. File name: D:\App\Math\Unt.nb.

Comment: This is not a real question because you are asking for someone to do a specific job for you. And BTW, the job is rather unpleasant.

Comment: -1 For asking the same question 3 times....

Comment: This question is not related to programming.

Comment: from prior experience, since this file is rather large, it was most likely corrupted when quitting while a save operation was occurring.  Hence, the problem is related to the operation of Mathematica, and not the programming of Mathematica.  This implies that it is best suited on superuser.com

Comment: @rcollyer I can confirm but probably you're right. I'm facing the problem a lot and my files are quite large and I schedule to save a file very 10 minutes.

Comment: @internet I try to limit the size of my notebooks to 100 MB, once past that I start to look into how best to split them up. Usually, this involves offloading a lot of the programming work into a package, likely multiple ones. I then look into splitting off the calculation portion into separate notebooks, or, better, result files that can be reloaded by the analysis code.

Answer (score 5):

Just a hint:

Open your notebook with a good editor. Your file is rather big, so I'll transcript just one line. Do the following:

```
CellPrint@Cell[CellGroupData[{
    Cell[BoxData[{RowBox[{
           RowBox[{
              RowBox[{"pp", "[", "n_", "]"}], ":=", 
              RowBox[{
                 RowBox[{"DivisorSigma", "[", 
                    RowBox[{"1", ",", "n"}], "]"}], "/", 
                 RowBox[{"(", 
                    RowBox[{"n", "*", 
                       RowBox[{"Log", "[", 
                          RowBox[{"Log", "[", "n", "]"}], "]"}]}], 
               ")"}]}]}], ";"}]}]]}]]
```

that gives you:

```
pp[n_]:=DivisorSigma[1,n]/(n*Log[Log[n]]);
```

Do that for every cell, or make a program to do that for you.

**Edit**

I was soft-hearted today, and decided to help you a little more ...

```
pp[n_]:=DivisorSigma[1,n]/(n*Log[Log[n]]);
mp[n_]:=Max[FactorInteger[n]];
g[n_]:=Product[If[Element[i,Primes],i,1],{i,1,n}];
k1=1;
k2=2;
k3=4;
k4=6;
k5=12;
k6=24;
k7=36;
k8=48;
k9=60;
k10=120;
k11=180;
k12=240;
k13=360;
k14=720;
k15=840;
k16=1260;
k17=1680;
k18=2520;
```

**But then I saw that you continue with that definitions for your k__ until k2000** , which is 310 digits long and then define almost oher 5000 independent variables more.

Sorry, but that is not the way to work with Mma. Corrupting your file was Mma sense of revenge.

Comment: Effectively you could use sed to strip Cell*, RowBox, [{, }], and all ,(commas) that are not enclosed in ". Then replace "x" -> x. and you're halfway there.

Comment: Also (as I said in a comment to his first question) there are some `Cell[]` objects that don't close properly - big chunks of data seem to be missing, so you won't be able to recover everything in his original notebook, even if you wanted to.  I hope he appreciates your soft, malleable heart nonetheless!

Comment: @Simon Yep. I did not follow the whole saga, but you are right. There are (at least) a few incomplete cells. Recovering the whole thing is a manual task that will take more time than learning Mma basics. Anyway I don't understand how defining 8000 independent vars doesn't lit some red light in your head ... in any language

Answer (score 0):

You should contact Wolfram technical support if you're having trouble.

http://www.wolfram.com/support/